# Applications of the (cumulated) ruler function in algorithm analysis

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, reference-request, recurrence-relation, divide-and-conquer

In Chapter 2 (Page 76) of the book ["An Introduction to the Analysis of Algorithms (2nd edition)"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/032190575X) by Robert Sedgewick and Philippe Flajolet, the authors introduce two functions:

> **Definition** Given an integer $N$, define the *ruler* function $\psi_N$ to be the number of trailing $1$s in the binary representation of $N$ and the *cumulated ruler* function $R_N$ to be the number of trailing $1$s in the binary representations of all the numbers less than $N$.

For example, $\psi_{83 = 1010011} = 2$ and $R_{15} = 11$.

However, no applications of these functions in algorithm analysis have been shown in this chapter. Are you aware of any applications of $\psi_N$ or $R_N$ in algorithm analysis, particularly of divide-and-conquer algorithms?

---

I ask applications for $\psi_N$ or $R_N$ because the book does provide nice relation between the analysis of binary divide-and-conquer algorithms (mergesort, in particular) and the other two binary representations related functions: one for counting the number of bits in the binary representations of the numbers less than $N$ and the other counting the number of $1$s in the binary representations of the numbers less than $N$.